# Do 1 sql select command which will work only with first 100 records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My problem is that when i do select command, application is very slowly because im doing select from table with 10000records but always i work only with about first 100 records. Is there option to say **do select but not from all table - for example. DO SELECT FROM TABLE, BUT WORK ONLY WITH FIRST 100 RECORDS?**

```
$time = mysql_query("KBD, jobNumber, truckid, SUM(pallets) as count_pallets, SUM(cartons) as count_cartons, COUNT(*) as pocet FROM incoming WHERE availableDate = '$today_date' AND slotTime = '$time' GROUP BY truckid,forwarder");
```

Comment: there is no "first 100" in mysql because the sequence is related to how you order the fields. Limit will affect only the number of rows returned not how many elaborated. You should analyze why your query is running slow. You probably need some indexes

Comment: Use Describe table to see what is the situation and try to understand what indexes you may need

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the amount of records in mysql by adding the limit clause at the end.

```
$time = mysql_query
("KBD, jobNumber, truckid, SUM(pallets) as count_pallets, 
SUM(cartons) as count_cartons, COUNT(*) as pocet 
FROM incoming 
WHERE availableDate = '$today_date' 
AND slotTime = '$time' 
GROUP BY truckid,forwarder 
LIMIT 100"
);
```

Comment: this will affect only how many rows SQL will return, not how many will be read by the select statements.

Comment: This should still help with the performance issues. I do agree with you that some indexes are probably needed.

Comment: no, it won't. The LIMIT command will just say "stop returning values after you have sent the first N" but the full table will be already parsed

Comment: @LelioFaieta you are right. So can you give me another advice/help?